# RTX 30 series gpu's with tensorflow 1.15 on windows doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, nvidia

I am trying to train a custom **tensorflow 1.15** ssd_mobilenet model on my **rtx 3070 gpu**. It works perfectly fine on the cpu, but doens't work with the gpu, because cuda 10.0 and tf 1.15 probably don't support rtx 30 series. I can't upgrade to tensorflow 2, because I am trying to run the tflite model on a *rev control hub*, and it just refuses to work with tensorflow 2.X models. I also tried installing `nvidia-pyindex` and `nvidia-tensorflow` and `nvidia-pyindex` installs just fine, but I always get an error when installing `nvidia-tensorflow`:

````
(tf2_convert) C:\Users\User>pip install nvidia-tensorflow
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting nvidia-tensorflow
  Downloading nvidia-tensorflow-0.0.1.dev5.tar.gz (7.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r91lrkf7\nvidia-tensorflow_9f358636cbbf402f81f9b2fea9d70d53\setup.py", line 150, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
      RuntimeError:
      ###########################################################################################
      The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
      This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.

      This package can be installed as:
      ```
      $ pip install nvidia-pyindex
      $ pip install nvidia-tensorflow
      ```

      Please refer to NVIDIA instructions: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow#install.
      ###########################################################################################

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
````

I think, this is caused, because I use windows, and I have heard, that nvidia-tensorflow is only supported on **linux** (**but I am NOT SURE**). *So is there a way to make rtx 30 series gpus work with tensorflow 1.15 on windows???*

Comment: I don't think you'll get the RTX 3070 working with TF1, as the library you've linked only supports Ubuntu (although you could try it in a VM/container running Ubuntu?). Alternatively can you train in TF2 and export your trained weights for use in an identical model developed in TF1 on the REV?

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. The most plausible solution for me would be to export the tf2 weights ant put them in a tf1 model. But how exactly should I export the weights? Am I supposed to just copy the tf2 generated checkpoints into a tf1 anaconda virtual env and just export it, or what?

Comment: I would try Keras's [`layer.get_weights()`](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#getweights-method) to get the raw weights for each layer in your trained TF2 model, then move them to the REV somehow and use [`layer.set_weights()`](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#setweights-method) to load those trained weights into the identical TF1 model. I say this because it doesn't rely on the TF version not having changed the save/load behaviour. But you could try [`tf.keras.Model.save_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save_weights).